# Custom string to bool conversion for sql/driver and Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, sqldatatypes

I am trying to create a string to bool converstion data type, **to further explain what I am trying to achieve I will give an example of a string concat**.

The following struct will fail at field 2 and 3 when using gorm, if you debug this it will basically throw an error saying `sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "nlfieldTwo": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *[]string;`

```
type Name struct {
   FieldOne   *String   `json:"fieldOne,omitempty"   gorm:"column:nlfieldOne"`
   FieldTwo   *[]String `json:"fieldTwo,omitempty"   gorm:"column:nlfieldTwo"`
   FieldThree *[]String `json:"fieldThree,omitempty" gorm:"column:nlfieldThree"`
}
```

A fix around this is to create your own type

```
type StringConcat []string

func (s *StringConcat) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    str, _ := value.([]byte)
    // log.Println(value)
    // if !ok {
    //  return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("Failed to unmarshal value:", value))
    // }

    *s = strings.Split(string(str), ",")
    return nil
}

// Value return json value, implement driver.Valuer interface
func (s StringConcat) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return strings.Join(s, ","), nil
}
```

and then simply replace `FieldTwo   *[]String` with `FieldTwo   StringConcat`

**THE PROBLEM**

I am trying to do something similar for a bool type as seen in `FieldFour`

```
type Name struct {
   FieldOne   *String   `json:"fieldOne,omitempty"   gorm:"column:nlfieldOne"`
   FieldTwo   *[]String `json:"fieldTwo,omitempty"   gorm:"column:nlfieldTwo"`
   FieldThree *[]String `json:"fieldThree,omitempty" gorm:"column:nlfieldThree"`
   FieldFour  *bool     `json:"fieldThree,omitempty" gorm:"column:nlfieldFour"`
}
```

FieldFour is a string type so if I try doing the above it will simply fail and throw an error `sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "nlfieldFour": sql/driver: couldn't convert "" into type bool; sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "nlfieldFour": sql/driver: couldn't convert "None" into type bool; sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "nlfieldFour": sql/driver: couldn't convert "Creative" into type bool; ....... and so on`

I am trying to convert that to return a bool however, I do not want to check for empty and None string values as shown in the error above `""` and `"None"` everything else I want to return a true if they got a string value or false if they got nothing.

I tried looking into `strconv.FormatBool` but I could not figure out a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

That should be doable by implementing your custom type as well:

```golang
type MyBool bool

func (s *MyBool) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, _ := value.(string)
    if b == "" || b == "None" {
        *s = false
    } else {
        *s = true
    }
    return nil
}

func (s MyBool) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if s {
        return "true", nil
    }
    return "", nil
}
```

I'm not sure, if I understood the required mapping right, but you should be able to adapt it. Define your mapping of `string` to `bool` in `Scan` and vice versa in `Value`.